# How to formulate Python regex to get btrfs subvol ID

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing `/etc/mtab` and want to capture the second field and a `subvol` or `subvolid` setting if any in the fourth field. However, I am having some trouble in formulating the correct regex. Please see:

```
import re
def test(regex):
    def helper(string):
        m = re.match(regex, string)
        if m is None: print("no matches")
        else: print(m.groups())
    helper("/dev/sdb2 /mnt/btrfs btrfs rw,noatime 0 0")
    helper("/dev/sdb2 /tmp btrfs rw,noatime,subvol=os-aux/kubuntu-lts/tmp 0 0")
    helper("/dev/sdb2 /tmp btrfs noatime,subvol=os-aux/kubuntu-lts/tmp,rw 0 0")
    helper("/dev/sdb2 /tmp btrfs subvol=os-aux/kubuntu-lts/tmp,rw,noatime 0 0")
```

The expected output is of course:

```
('/mnt/btrfs', None)
('/tmp', 'subvol=os-aux/kubuntu-lts/tmp')
('/tmp', 'subvol=os-aux/kubuntu-lts/tmp')
('/tmp', 'subvol=os-aux/kubuntu-lts/tmp')
```

Now my experiments and their results are shown:

```
>>> test("\S+ (\S+) \S+ \S+(subvol(?:id)?=[^ ,]+)?")
('/mnt/btrfs', None)
('/tmp', None)
('/tmp', None)
('/tmp', None)
>>> test("\S+ (\S+) \S+ \S+?(subvol(?:id)?=[^ ,]+)?")
('/mnt/btrfs', None)
('/tmp', None)
('/tmp', None)
('/tmp', None)
>>> test("\S+ (\S+) \S+ \S+(subvol(?:id)?=[^ ,]+)")
no matches
('/tmp', 'subvol=os-aux/kubuntu-lts/tmp')
('/tmp', 'subvol=os-aux/kubuntu-lts/tmp')
no matches
```

What am I doing wrong? How to formulate a regex to achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using something like https://regex101.com/#python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one works for me

```
\S+ (\S+) \S+ \S*(subvol(?:id)?=[^ ,]*)
```

also, this is a super useful website for regex
https://www.debuggex.com/

EDIT:

this one also matches for ones without subvol:

```
\S+ (\S+) \S+ (?:\S*(subvol(?:id)?=[^ ,]*)|\S*)
```

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't test correctly for the first sample line i.e. without `subvol`...